# How can I know when\if an ActiveRecord collection is or not is lazy loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, lazy-loading

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to know whether an ActiveRecord collection (for example that generated by `@user.articles`) is lazy loaded or  not. That is, I would like to know a "general" way to do that without reading the RoR documentation where it specifies explicitly when an ActiveRecord is lazy loaded.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with the [loaded?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationProxy/loaded?) method.

e.g.

```
@user.articles.loaded?
```